# When user scrolls down to image position, execute transformation

Tags: javascript, css

The console.log's are working as expected, however the transformation only gets added to the img when we reach the bottom of the page, not when we are 400px from the bottom of the page. Anything I'm missing?

```js
let nextProjectImage = document.querySelector('.next-project-img');


zoomOutOnScroll = () => {
    let scrollHeight = document.documentElement.scrollHeight;
    let scrollPosition = window.innerHeight + window.pageYOffset;
    let distanceFromBottom = scrollHeight - scrollPosition;
    console.log(distanceFromBottom);
    if ((distanceFromBottom) < 400) {
        console.log('execute');
        nextProjectImage.style.transform = `translate3d(0px, ${-(distanceFromBottom)}, 0px`;
    }
    else {
        console.log("not close enough");
    }
}

document.addEventListener("scroll", zoomOutOnScroll);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this:

```
${-(distanceFromBottom)}
```

If you replace it with a fixed/valid value, it works as expected. Not sure what you wanted to do with this, but it looks like the value is correct only after you reach the bottom and the value of this expression hits 0. All the "higher" values aren't numbers with 'px' at the end, hence the transform isn't applied.

Maybe something like this?

```
nextProjectImage.style.transform = 'translate3d(0px, ' + -distanceFromBottom + 'px, 0px)';
```

Comment: Damn, just forgot to put the px! Thanks for spotting that Rok!